# Download exported Mikrotik config

Tags: backup, mikrotik

I've read how to, and successfully created and `export` of my configuration. The [documentation](http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:Configuration_Management#System_Backup) says the exports can be downloaded via FTP, but provide no details.

Anybody know how to download an export?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since the '/export' command dumps the configuration to stdout, I do always backup my mikrotiks vía ssh this way:

```
 ~$ ssh admin@router /export > mikrotik.conf
```

Comment: This should work. If you have ftp configured as a service in mikrotik than you should be able to download this file. You can also get it via winbox.

Comment: Wicked! I was logging in and running the `/export` command. Seems it doesn't output to stdout in that case. This is even better though, because I don't have to setup FTP on the Mikrotik, and it will be easy to script an external backup. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

First off, the use of FTP is NOT recommended as your password is sent in cleartext, and anyone looking at your traffic can sniff it.

IF you want to use FTP, make sure it is enabled under `IP > Services`. Then go to your terminal, and export the file using the command `export file=myname`. The file will then be under the `File` menu as `myname.rsc`.

You then browse to your router's external IP address in a browser, or just in Windows Explorer, using `ftp://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX` and log in. You will be able to Right click on the file and `Save As` to your computer.

Answer (score 3):

A small addition:

You can actually use SFTP in case you are using ssh-keys to access the System. See the MikroTik wiki: https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Using_SSH_for_system_backup

> Though not well documented, the Mikrotik supports sftp using the same ssh key system

Would be something like that (if you have a ssh-agent that handles the key):

`sftp myuser@mymtik:todays_mtik.backup ./local_backup_dir/todays_mtik.backup`

Or use the arguments `-i` or `-oIdentityFile=` to specify the ssh key you are using to connect:

`sftp -i ~/.ssh/my-ssh-key myuser@mymtik:todays_mtik.backup ./local_backup_dir/todays_mtik.backup`

Comment: Nice tip - upvote from me!